# Flash Crossdomain.xml Problems

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, crossdomain.xml, gravatar

I'm trying to load Gravatars into Flash.  Luckily, they provided a crossdomain.xml file at `http://en.gravatar.com/avatar/crossdomain.xml`

My code:

```
Security.loadPolicyFile("http://en.gravatar.com/avatar/crossdomain.xml");
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.load(new URLRequest("http://en.gravatar.com/avatar/" + gravatar + "?s=35&d=identicon"));
```

But I'm still getting this error:

> SecurityError: Error #2123: Security sandbox violation: LoaderInfo.content: [...] cannot access http://en.gravatar.com/avatar/97fbce86a5bbc520450168603172cd9e?s=35&d=identicon. No policy files granted access.
>   at flash.display::LoaderInfo/get content()
>   at PiecePlayerSmall/onLoadComplete()

I also monitored the traffic the Flash file is sending.  It's requesting:

- My domain's crossdomain.xml file
- "http://en.gravatar.com/avatar/crossdomain.xml"
- "http://en.gravatar.com/crossdomain.xml"
- "http://en.gravatar.com/"
- then, http://en.gravatar.com/avatar/97fbce86a5bbc520450168603172cd9e?s=35&d=identicon

Any suggestions for getting this to work and reducing the number of requests to gravatar.com.

**EDIT:**
The following code works, thanks to Jacob

```
Security.loadPolicyFile("http://en.gravatar.com/avatar/crossdomain.xml");
var context:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext();
context.checkPolicyFile = true;
context.applicationDomain = ApplicationDomain.currentDomain;
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(
    "http://en.gravatar.com/avatar/" + gravatar + "?s=35&d=identicon");
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.load(request, context);
this.addChild(loader);
```

Note: Do not try to access the content directly in the Event.COMPLETE

Comment: what if my request URL is not on my current domain?

Comment: If it's not your current domain, it means you have no permission to access their resources. In this case, you need to do some hack methods to inline modify the crossdomain.xml.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got around a similar issue by using a [LoaderContext](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/system/LoaderContext.html).  Here's an example of how to do this:

```
var context:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext();
context.checkPolicyFile = true;
context.securityDomain = SecurityDomain.currentDomain;
context.applicationDomain = ApplicationDomain.currentDomain;
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(
    "http://en.gravatar.com/avatar/" + gravatar + "?s=35&d=identicon");
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.load(request, context);
```

Comment: Just tried that, new error: Error #2044: Unhandled SecurityErrorEvent:. text=Error #2048: Security sandbox violation: [...] cannot load data from http://en.gravatar.com/avatar/97fbce86a5bbc520450168603172cd9e?s=35&d=identicon.

Comment: Okay, this solved my problem!  Don't add the SecurityDomain though, it only makes things worse.  Also, you cannot directly access the content of the Loader, that throws another error.

Comment: @John how should you access the content then?